# Android Studio 2.1 using Navigation Drawer Activity error

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio-2.1

I created a new Activity with the **NavigationDrawerTemplate** on Android Studio

This is what the code created for the **.java** class file

> Homescreen.java

```
public class Homescreen extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_homescreen);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.homescreen, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

When the template is created all the icons for the side nav bar icons are in .xml format

One example is **ic_menu_gallery.xml**  which creates an icon of a gallery picture

```
    <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M22,16V4c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2H8c-1.1,0 -2,0.9 -2,2v12c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2h12c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2zm-11,-4l2.03,2.71L16,11l4,5H8l3,-4zM2,6v14c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2h14v-2H4V6H2z" />
</vector>
```

However, when I try to change this to a **PNG** file it throws the error

> 08-17 19:31:33.257 10228-10228/com.example.dd.ee_android_appliction E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.dd.ee_android_appliction/com.example.dd.ee_android_appliction.Homescreen}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error
>   inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
>                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:148)
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1319)
>                                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5457)
>                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>                                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:854)
>                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
>                                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16:
>   Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
>                                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
>                                                                                                 at
>   com.example.dd.ee_android_appliction.Homescreen.onCreate(Homescreen.java:22)
>                                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5234)
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388) 
>                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:148) 
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1319) 
>                                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>                                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5457) 
>                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
>                                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:854) 
>                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670) 
>                                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
>                                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
>                                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
>                                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
>                                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249) 
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106) 
>                                                                                                 at
>   com.example.dd.ee_android_appliction.Homescreen.onCreate(Homescreen.java:22) 
>                                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5234) 
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302) 
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388) 
>                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:148) 
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1319) 
>                                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>                                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5457) 
>                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
>                                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:854) 
>                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670) 
>                                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.content.res.ResourcesEx.getThemeDrawable(ResourcesEx.java:456)
>                                                                                                 at android.content.res.ResourcesEx.loadDrawable(ResourcesEx.java:432)
>                                                                                                 at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:702)
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:321)
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager.getDrawable(TintManager.java:145)
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:422)
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.prepareMenuItems(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:383)
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:255)
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.getMenuView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:97)
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.(NavigationView.java:149)
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.(NavigationView.java:88)
>                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
>                                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
>                                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
>                                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
>                                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
>                                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249) 
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106) 
>                                                                                                 at
>   com.example.dd.ee_android_appliction.Homescreen.onCreate(Homescreen.java:22) 
>                                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5234) 
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302) 
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388) 
>                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:148) 
>                                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1319) 
>                                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>                                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5457) 
>                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
>                                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:854) 
>                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670) 
>                                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

How what should i do to be able to import **PNG** icons as my navigation bar icons instead of **XML** format?

### EDIT:

As requested here is the homescreen layout xml code thank you!

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_homescreen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_homescreen"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_homescreen_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please post the `activity_homescreen` layout file too?

Comment: You want menu icon as PNG?

Comment: just paste png icons into respective drawable folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### In **drawable-v21** that is default in your case contains **[VectorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html)**

[image]

#### So what you can do is delete folder **drawable-v21** or single file.

And add `.png` with same name.

Comment: Apparently there was a folder issue, the Android Studio couldn't recognise the drawable or drawable-v21. I reset Android Studio and created a new project and manually pasted my PNG image and now it works ! Thank you so much !